# Get the list of installed libraries across all databricks workspace clusters

Tags: command-line-interface, databricks, azure-powershell, azure-databricks

How do I get the list of all libraries installed on each cluster on databricks workspace. I have a scenario where more than 20 clusters are running on single workspace hence looking for a way to fetch this info using scripts

Checked [Workspace CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#list) option but that doesn't seem to give required info.

Looking for 4 columns in output i.e. Name, Type, Status & Source as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it based on the following steps.

**Step-01**: Get the list of available clusters and their respective `cluster-id` based on the following python code and create list for `cluster-id`

```
from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.clusters.api import ClusterApi
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

apiclient = ApiClient(token = dbutils.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().apiToken().get(),
                   host = dbutils.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().apiUrl().get())
cluster_api = ClusterApi(apiclient)
import json
cluster_list = cluster_api.list_clusters()
rdd = sc.parallelize(cluster_list['clusters']).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
raw_clusters_df = spark.read.json(rdd)
parsed_clusters_df = raw_clusters_df.select(
  'cluster_name',
  'cluster_id').orderBy('cluster_name', ascending=True)
display(parsed_clusters_df)
```

**Step-02** : You can iterate this list and pass every it every cluster-id to `library API`

```
%sh
export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=<Personal Access Token>
curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN" \
curl --netrc --request GET 'https://instance-id/api/2.0/libraries/cluster-status?cluster_id=clusterid'
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks @Karthikeyan,  is there a way to store this curl output in dataframe ?

Comment: yes.. You can use following steps. (Just a logic) 1. execute the curl command through python code 2. convert that result into python list 3. convert respect list into dataframe

Comment: thank you @Karthikeyan, this helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a dedicated [Libraries API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries.html) for that. Specifically, [Cluster Status](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries.html#cluster-status) command that will give you a list of installed libraries & their status (example from docs):

```json
{
  "cluster_id": "11203-my-cluster",
  "library_statuses": [
    {
      "library": {
        "jar": "dbfs:/mnt/libraries/library.jar"
      },
      "status": "INSTALLED",
      "messages": [],
      "is_library_for_all_clusters": false
    },
    {
      "library": {
        "pypi": {
          "package": "beautifulsoup4"
        },
      },
      "status": "INSTALLING",
      "messages": ["Successfully resolved package from PyPI"],
      "is_library_for_all_clusters": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you, this helped!