# Azure Databricks - Check version of installed JDBC

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

Using an [Azure Active Directory Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals), I'm trying to connect to `Azure SQL Db` from a `notebook` in `Azure Databricks`. I'm trying to use `Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server`
as discussed in this [article from Azure team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16):

**Question**: In a python notebook in Azure Databricks, how do I check which version of Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server is used?

Based on the following quote from [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16), I need to verify if I have driver version 9.2 installed

```
ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal
Since driver version v9.2, authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal can be used to connect to an Azure SQL Database/Synapse Analytics by specifying the application/client ID in the userName property and secret of a service principal identity in the password property.
```

Comment: As documented in a [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases) JDBC driver for MSSQL version 9.2.1.jre8 is already included in the Databricks runtime.

Comment: @PratikLad-MT I did `ctrl+F` on your linked page, and searched for `jdbc`. I did not find any mention of jdbc. What I may be missing? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the list of installed libraries across all databricks workspace clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213373/get-the-list-of-installed-libraries-across-all-databricks-workspace-clusters)

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy Unfortunately that won't list the version of the driver/s.